# MySQL issue with subqueries in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I need to use subqueries to name columns in a query. I have written a statement with subqueries in the `SELECT` section, but I am getting the following error message (returned from Codeigniter):

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '1'), `psc_opt_2` A' at line 1

```
SELECT
    `psc_opt_1` AS (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '1'),
    `psc_opt_2` AS (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '2'),
    `psc_opt_3` AS (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '3'),
    `psc_opt_4` AS (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '4'),
    `psc_opt_5` AS (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '5')
FROM (`product_stock_control`)
WHERE `psc_prod_id` = '5'
```

> Filename: models/products_model.php
>
> Line Number: 602

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: there are php functions that allow you to extract column names from a table.... have you check that out?  it looks like you are executing this within some php code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AS` is a column alias operator, meaning you are selecting these variables as an identifier. You cannot use the operator to identify a variable with a query.

**Reference**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Instead, you'll need to reverse how you use the alias operator like so:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '1') AS `psc_opt_1`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '2') AS `psc_opt_2`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '3') AS `psc_opt_3`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '4') AS `psc_opt_4`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '5') AS `psc_opt_5`
FROM (`product_stock_control`)
WHERE `psc_prod_id` = '5'
```

Ideally, you should avoid using subqueries (especially in this case) to avoid table-locking overhead.

Answer (score 0):

correct format is

```
(SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '1') As `psc_opt_1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '1') as `psc_opt_1`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '2') as `psc_opt_2`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '3') as `psc_opt_3`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '4') as `psc_opt_4`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '5') as `psc_opt_5`
FROM (`product_stock_control`)
WHERE `psc_prod_id` = '5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to name this columns psc_opt_1 to psc_opt_1 or what what do you exactly want to?

Naming would be like this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '1') AS `psc_opt_1`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '2') AS `psc_opt_2`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '3') AS `psc_opt_3`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '4') AS `psc_opt_4`,
    (SELECT `ps_url_name` FROM `product_selects` WHERE `ps_id` = '5') AS `psc_opt_5`
FROM (`product_stock_control`)
WHERE `psc_prod_id` = '5'
```